# how to reconnect to cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

In my one of my application I am creating keyspaces in 4 node cassandra cluster, And I have a condition to check if actually keyspace created or not and if cluster is not able to create keyspace then I am trying to recreate the keyspace X number of times. So in this case requirement is in each try I want to close connection to cassandra and re-create it then try creating the keyspace/table again. How to do this in better way ?

```
int retry = 5;

for loop......{
  if(!checkIfKeyspaceCreated(keyspaceName) && retryCount < 5 )
  {
  retry++;
  continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your overall goal here? The reason I ask is that programmatic creation / destruction of keyspaces and / or tables with Cassandra can lead to problems if its done too often / too fast (think convergence of distributed systems etc). Its not impossible but just that I've seen problems with these kind of actions in various circumstances

Comment: @Neil, sometimes in my application, query of keyspace creation getting fail due to failure in achieving the CONSISTENCY level or it might be cassandra instance goes down. So what I want here if anything goes wrong with keyspace creation I want to retry it with my custom code.